# External links have a "ga-ft" cookie parameter being appended to the URL

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I'm working with a site - https://www.graduatehotels.com/cambridge/around-town/ - and whenever you click an external link, there is a "ga-ft" cookie being appended to it on the other website. For example, the first "see menu" buttons lands me on this - https://www.greeneking-pubs.co.uk/pubs/cambridgeshire/eagle/menu/?_ga-ft=1XkY5P.0.0.0.0.WeI99N-1OvM6OI.0.1

I need to know how to prevent this from happening. I'm very attuned to cross domain tracking and have that set up just for the two URL's we need. This external link thing is throwing me off.

In this past I've heard "ga-ft" is a Google Analtyics 4 cookie, is that correct?

Answer (score 1):

Just go to GTM and disable the linker.
Or remove the domains you don't want to link your corss-domain tracking with.

But this will result in you having different client ids for users moving from one site to the other. It will make it much more complex to trace user journey across domains.

You can implement cross-domain linking on the backend in case all backends in question can communicate freely and set correct ga cookie.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So this is a URL that I do not want cross-domain tracking on. It is a a link to another website we have no relationship to (i.e. no tracking on that site) - Any idea why it still appends despite not being included in my tracking setup?

Comment: it must be included at some point, check your setup. if you can't find it, block GTM completely from execution, reload the page and try again. But then, if it's an unrelated site, why would you care what's appended to its URL?

Comment: I can assure its not. And totally agree with you, but I'm in the world of client services so I need to exhaust all options for them. I appreciate your help on this!